# PHP user management with user profiles, credit system for user group to view profiles

Tags: php, mysql, profiles

I've been asked to do a project for someone and they are on a low budget, so I was hoping to maybe find a script online that I can work with, but not being able to so I thought I'd ask around. This is what it is needs to do in a but shell:

- Will have user profile pages for customers
- User group for agent login whom can credit account for credits, and those credits can be used to view details from a specied user profile
- Guess need to set packages for credits, such as $150 for 100 credits, cost to view profile information will cost 1 credit and when runs out they have to top up

Something along those lines...

Is there something that can do that? Of course, it will need an administration area to manage it.

If possible, PHP and MySQL based.

Comment: I don't believe this is a good question. Search the web for a solution, ask a forum or search a script repository, e.g. here: http://www.phpclasses.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One place you could start is http://www.webintersect.com/. It's under the GNU GPL. It might give you an idea of where to begin.

Comment: Do you know if there is an online demo of that software online? would be good to see online rather than having to download and setup. Also do you know what features it has etc.... as not really any description or documentation about it.